# Java generic type resolution

Tags: java, generics

I have started to work with Java recently and still got confused when dealing with generic types. The following is a simplified scenario where I am having some problems.

I have a class wich holds a Map using a Class type as Key and an Collection of objects of that class:

```
public class GenericListInside {
    private Map<Class<?>, List<?>> mapping = new HashMap<>();

    public <T> void addListing(Class<T> clazz, List<T> object) {
        mapping.put(clazz, object);
    }
}
```

I can call addListing without problems:

```
GenericListInside gli = new GenericListInside();
List<Foo> list = new ArrayList<>(); 
//add something to list
gli.addListing(Foo.class, list);
```

Now i decided to create a Class to provide a fluid interface. Something like:

```
with(Foo.class).use(list);
```

Then i came with:

```
public class FluidInserter<T> {
    Class<T> clazz;
    GenericListInside gli = new GenericListInside();

    public FluidInserter with (Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        return this;
    }

    public <T> void use(List<T> list) {
        gli.addListing(clazz, list);
    }
}
```

But when I try to compile I get:

> Error:(18, 12) java: method addListing in class util.GenericListInside cannot be applied to given types;
>     required: java.lang.Class,java.util.List
>     found: java.lang.Class,java.util.List
>     reason: inferred type does not conform to equality constraint(s)
>       inferred: T
>       equality constraints(s): T,T

This message is a little bit confusing... can anyone figure out what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The generic method of your fluid builder takes a generic method parameter, but that parameter is not the same as the type of your `clazz` field, despite the name overlap.

Just remove `<T>` from your method declaration, while leaving `List<T>` as parameter:

```
public void use(List<T> list) {
    gli.addListing(clazz, list);
}
```

Off-topic note: you don't want to return a raw typed `FluidInserter` in your `with` method. Change the return type to:

```
public FluidInserter<T> with (Class<T> clazz)
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with the definition of your `use(List<T> list)` method:

```
public <T> void use(List<T> list) {
    gli.addListing(clazz, list);
}
```

Here, you're *hiding* the class-scoped type-parameter `T`, by introducing a method-scoped type-parameter with the same name.

It should rather be:

```
public void use(List<T> list) {
    gli.addListing(clazz, list);
}
```

and it should compile just fine, as `T` is already defined on class level.

Answer (score 3):

You problem is the following declaration:

```
public <T> void use(List<T> list) {
    gli.addListing(clazz, list);
}
```

As you have already defined the generic `<T>` on the class level, there is no need to generify the method.

I suggest you change the signature to the following:

```
public void use(List<? extends T> list) {
    // same logic here
}
```

Also, as a side note, I think you should also make the `GenericListInside` generic. Right now the definition of the `mapping` field permits mixing types in the key and the value, which is something you don't want.

**Edit**

You can add a generic to the `GenericListInside` like this:

```
public class GenericListInside<T> {

    private final Map<Class<T>, List<T> mapping = new HashMap<>();

    public void addListing(Class<T> clazz, List<T> list) {
        mapping.put(clazz, list);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Danail! About your last comment: I was really concerned about the types inside the mapping field and hope that the addListing method can guarantee the cohesion. I could not figure out how I can solve this problem making the class generic. Could you elaborate a little bit more about tha please?

Comment: @marcellorvalle Check out the update I made to my answer.

Comment: At first glance a thought this would limit my map to a single class type. As I tested it I saw it is not true. I need to take a deeper look at generics... Thanks!